# mysql query four releated tables to toal number of votes per district

Tags: php, mysql

Table "**tblvotes**"

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| candidateid | int(11) | NO | MUL | NULL |  |
| districtid | int(11) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| daterecorded | datetime | NO |  | current_timestamp() |  |

Table "**tblcandidate**":

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| voterid | int(11) | NO | MUL | NULL |  |
| partyid | int(11) | NO | MUL | NULL |  |
| candidatepositionid | int(11) | NO | MUL | NULL |  |

Table "**tbldistricts**":

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| district_short | varchar(8) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| district_name | varchar(100) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| district_aun | varchar(10) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| district_propVal | tinyint(4) | NO |  | 1 |  |

Table "**tblvoterlist**":

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| idno | varchar(15) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| lastname | varchar(30) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| firstname | varchar(30) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| middlename | varchar(30) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| districtid | int(5) | YES | MUL | NULL |  |
| image | varchar(30) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| votingcode | varchar(15) | YES | UNI | NULL |  |
| votestatus | char(1) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| yearlevelid | int(12) | YES | MUL | NULL |  |

```
SELECT concat_ws(",", tvl.lastname, tvl.firstname) as candidate, td.district_name as district,  count(tv.candidateid) 
FROM tblvotes tv
JOIN tblcandidate tc on tv.candidateid = tc.id
JOIN tbldistricts td on tv.districtid = td.id
JOIN tblvoterlist tvl on tc.voterid = tvl.id
```

Also tried to group by tv.districtid and I am not sure where the COUNT should be.

unfortunately, I really am not understanding how use the keys to get the desired result.

As an example the desired result is:

|  | Candidate1 | Canddiate2 | Candidate3 | Candidate4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| District1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| District2 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| District3 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you want each candidate in a different column, you need to [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Try this and see if this is what you want..


SELECT 
    concat_ws(",", tvl.lastname, tvl.firstname) as candidate, 
    td.district_name as district, 
    COUNT(tv.candidateid) as votes
FROM tblvotes tv
JOIN tblcandidate tc on tv.candidateid = tc.id
JOIN tbldistricts td on tv.districtid = td.id
JOIN tblvoterlist tvl on tc.voterid = tvl.id
GROUP BY td.district_name, tvl.lastname, tvl.firstname
ORDER BY td.district_name, votes DESC

Comment: Thank you Barmar, Unless I am misunderstanding, I just need to figure out how to get the totals for each candidate by district from the four tables. I will put the results in an array and then produce a table or excel workbook or just print it out.

Comment: Thank you Gihan, I think your solution will work. I appreciate it!

Comment: This question would be more inviting to contributors if you would set up a working sql sandbox demo with sample data and your desired results for that sample data. @Lin